# AVI Animations for GUI

Tags: delphi, user-interface, animation, vcl, avi

I need to get some AVI animations for use with the Borland VCL TAnimate component, to display during operations such as 'online update', 'burning cd' and a few others.

I have only come across the [glyFX Animation Pack](http://www.glyfx.com/shop/detail/animationpack/) so far.

Can anybody recomend other places to get nice avi animations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using GIF animations instead of AVIs. There are a lots of them on the Web. There are also some free Delphi components working with animated GIFs, look [TGIFImage for Delphi](http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/) for example.